# Hyperledger Fabric - Latest documentation to setup local vagrant development environment

Tags: vagrant, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

Last month I followed the steps in the link https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/Setup/Chaincode-setup.md#running-the-chaincode and was able to run, invoke, query the chaincode successfully.

Today when I tried to follow the same steps to setup vagrant environment in another laptop, I found that there are some changes to the latest master in github like removal of membersrvc in makefile, peer network option not available etc. Hence above steps does not work anymore.

Does anyone know where is the latest documentation to setup vagrant environment locally?

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue a few weeks ago. You can try to switch from master branch to remotes/origin/v0.6 branch before doing setup.

Comment: Yes, thats what I finally did. 0.6 version works fine. But there seems no documentation available for 0.7